# Can't import the movie_lens datasets from tensorflow_datasets in google colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am learning python now.
When i am trying to import the movie_lens/100k-ratings data to my project, an error occur

```
DatasetNotFoundError: Dataset movie_lens not found.
```

Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs
ratings = tfds.load("movie_lens/100k-ratings", split="train")
```

From [the tensorflow page](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/movie_lens?hl=zh-tw#movie_lens100k-ratings), i should be able to import it from tfds.load
what should i do to fix this? thanks

Comment: what tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: i am using google colab, and the tensorflow version is 2.3.0

Comment: Movie_lens is only on the nightly release. Sry :/

Answer (score 3):

The movielens data set isn't in the `tensorflow-datasets` version that Google Colab currently uses by default (2.1.0 as of this writing).

Before trying to load the data set, you currently need to install the more up-to-date version of tensorflow datasets. Try running `!pip install tfds-nightly` before importing tensorflow datasets in your notebook.

See here for more info on the nightly package vs. full release: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/overview